# How to split up comma separated strings from a .txt file into separate files each containing a data column?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am beginner in scripting language and wanted to write a batch script by which I can get separate new .txt files each with a data column by reading a .txt file which contains comma separated strings as shown below:

```
James,10098,Jan
Arthur,19086,Feb
Katerina,10000,Mar
```

After getting the output, I want to have an array for the strings so that I can use them in another batch script.

Below script is what I have tried, but which is not worked the way I want it.

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set outputPath="C:\Users\Ben Martin\Test Scripts\"

set index=0

for /f "delims=," %%x in (Demo_MData.txt) do (
    set A[!index!] = %%x
    set /a index +=1
)

 cd %outputPath%
 Set A > %~n0_Output.txt
```

The current output in a single new separated file is:

```
A[0]=James
A[1]=Arthur
A[2]=Katerina
```

The expected output should be in three new separated files.

**Example1.txt**

```
James
Arthur
Katerina
```

**Example2.txt**

```
10098
19086
10000
```

**Example3.txt**

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
```

Comment: The first command line should be `@echo off`. The second command line should be `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`. The third command line should be `set "outputPath=%UserProfile%\Test Scripts"` and the fourth command line should be `del /A /F /Q "%outputPath%\Example?.txt" 2>nul`. Use as __FOR__ command line: `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%G in (Demo_MData.txt) do echo(%%G>>"%outputPath%\Example1.txt" & echo(%%H>>"%outputPath%\Example2.txt" & echo(%%I>>"%outputPath%\Example3.txt"` which can be of course written in the batch file also as multi-line __FOR__ loop.

Comment: The last command line should be `endlocal`. The usage of PowerShell instead of a batch file processed by the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` is better as PowerShell has true CSV support built-in while `cmd.exe` does not have. The posted __FOR__ command line does not work correct if there is an empty value like `Ben,,Dec` or a value with a comma like `"Company, Inc.",15323,Apr` or a multi-line value as described by the Wikipedia article about [comma-separated values](/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: Hi @Mofi Great!, you did a magic. It solved the problem ...please let me know how did you learn this ? I really appreciate it . I didn't even thought of using 'del' command

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=," %%g in (Demo_MData.txt) do (
 set "G[!index!]=%%g"
 set "H[!index!]=%%h"
 set "I[!index!]=%%i"
 set /a index +=1
 )
```

then

```
set G[>gfile.txt
```

.

```
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
```

Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N".  Remove <kbd>Space</kbd> from **both** sides of the `=`.

Using `set G[` to output t a file causes all variables starting `G[` to be listed.

Comment: instead of creating arrays, I would simply `>> example1.txt echo %%g` etc (accepting performance disadvantage; shouldn't be noticeable unless the file is quite big). Note: `set G[` might be suboptimal if there are more than 9 lines (sorting).